# read text file usign dlmread in Matlab

Tags: matlab, text-files, ascii

I have a text file to be red, havign the following structure:

```
       var1            var2            var3            var4 

   0.000000       -0.000000        0.000000        0.000000 
   0.011000       -0.000000        0.000000        0.000000 
   0.021000       -0.000000        0.000000        0.000000 
        ...             ...             ...             ...
```

in Matlab 2015 i used:

```
dlmread(file_path,'\t', 1, 0);
```

to skip the first row. It worked fine. Now in matlab 2017a the outpot is a row. Matlab sorts each row in a column so that the output is a column vector. Furthermore, the delimiter of each row of my text file are "CR""LF". I fixed the problem in this way:

```
dlmread(file_path,'\lf ',1,0);
```

But I get this warning

> Warning: Escaped character '\l' is not valid. See 'doc sprintf' for
>   supported special characters.

Comment: You didn't say how you fixed the problem. You just said, "I fixed the problem in this way:"

Comment: right. I fixed it

Comment: I think there are a couple things wrong here. First, a carriage return and line feed is represented by the control characters \r\n, not \lf. The \l is what's causing the warning. Secondly, the delimiter property in dlmread is for the delimiter between values, not the line ending. If you're having trouble with dlmread, look into importdata, textscan, or fscanf.